# How to organize Controllers and Views (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I want my `UITabBarController` to be with frame (0;100;320;380).

In addition to UITabBarController I want to have a view with frame (0;0;320;100).

This view is supposed to be independent from TabBarController and always visible. When different Tabs are opened top view should remain visible, like `UINavigationBar`.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `UIViewController` subclass, in the xib add two views, one `upperview` and another `lowerview` with the sizes you want

In the view did load of this view controller, create a `UITabBarController`, and add to it the view controllers you wish

then do

```
[lowerview addSubView:tabBarController.view];
[upperview addSubView:yourUpperView];
```